# How to create VSCode extension with standalone Next.js app

Tags: next.js, build, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a VSCode extension on top of a standalone Next.js app, similar to the CRA example here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit-samples/tree/main/frameworks/hello-world-react-cra.

However, I'm having trouble configuring things correctly.

When I run my extension in development mode, I get a [blank panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IloIj.png).

For my app, I'm using the Next.js starter (npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/main/basics/learn-starter") and have made the following edits to `hello-world-react-cra`:

1. in `package.json`, changed all scripts to point to `nextjs-blog` instead of `webview-ui`
2. in `HelloWorldPanel.ts`, restricted the webview to only load resources from the `out` and `nextjs-blog/.next` directories

```
localResourceRoots: [Uri.joinPath(extensionUri, "out"), Uri.joinPath(extensionUri, "nextjs-blog/.next")]
```

3. also in `HelloWorldPanel.ts`, changed the script URI

```
    const scriptUri = getUri(webview, extensionUri, [
      "nextjs-blog",
      ".next",
      "static",
      "chunks",
      "pages",
      "index.js"
    ]);
```

(I also tried

```
    const scriptUri = getUri(webview, extensionUri, [
      "nextjs-blog",
      ".next",
      "server",
      "pages",
      "index.js",
    ]);
```

)

4. in `package.json` and `extension.ts`, changed the command name from `hello-world` to `nextjs-blog`, just for good measure

For now, I'm using the `.next` build generated by `npm run dev` to avoid chunking and output file name hashing. It seems it's necessary to disable these for a production build to work anyway.

What could I be missing? Thanks for the help in advance!